# PaintComponent is not being called

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I´m just starting to learn how to program so excuse me if my question is just silly. I have been trying for over two days to find a solution for this problem and I just can't find it over the net so I need your help. Thanks in advance.

So, I am trying to recreate the Parchisi game in Java. I want to create a method that puts a counter in an specific position every time a player rolls the dice and obtains the number five as a result.
The counter has its own class, that is:

```
package parchis;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ficha extends JPanel
{
   public static int x;
   public static int y;
   public Image imagenficha;

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

  super.paintComponent(g);

  System.out.println("Ejecutándose función de pintura de ficha");
  g.drawImage(imagenficha,x,y,this);
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
}

 Ficha(int color, int locx, int locy, int ancho, int alto){

    this.setSize(60,60);
    System.out.println("El color es el "+Servidor.turno); 
    this.setBounds(locx,locy,ancho,alto); 
    x=locx;
    y=locy;
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

The checker is put over a jframe by a call of this method:

```
public void pintarficha(){

    Ficha ficha = new Ficha(Servidor.turno,40,40,100,100);
    jframe.getContentPane().add(ficha);
    Refrescar();
}
```

Refrescar:

```
public static void Refrescar(){

   jpanel.add(jlabel);
   jframe.add(jpanel);
  jframe.pack();
}
```

The problem is that, when the method pintarficha() is called from outside a method (I.E. in the instantiation of one of my classes) it works properly and paints the counter, but when I put it inside of any method, PaintComponent is not being executed and I cannot understand why.

Here it works:

```
package parchis;
public class Administradordereglas {

      Administradordereglas(){
        ********** Menu.menu.pintarficha(); ****************
      }

     void juegodebots(int jugador){

         System.out.println("LLAMADA A JUEGO DE BOTS");
         int valoraañadiralasposiciones;
         valoraañadiralasposiciones= Ventanadeordenes.dado.Tiraeldado();  

         if(valoraañadiralasposiciones==5){

            System.out.println("Se ha sacado un 5, procedo a crear una nueva ficha");
         }

         Parchis.servidor.Pasarturno();
     }
}
```

But here it doesn't:

```
package parchis;
public class Administradordereglas {

      Administradordereglas(){

      }
     void juegodebots(int jugador) {

         System.out.println("LLAMADA A JUEGO DE BOTS");
         int valoraañadiralasposiciones;
         valoraañadiralasposiciones= Ventanadeordenes.dado.Tiraeldado();  
         if(valoraañadiralasposiciones==5){
             **************This message appears in the console:****************** 
             System.out.println("Se ha sacado un 5, procedo a crear una nueva ficha");

            *****************Menu.menu.pintarficha();*************************
         }
         Parchis.servidor.Pasarturno();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is contained within the Pasarturno method? Ultimately you need to call repaint() on the Fischa component.

Comment: Pasarturno() just increases in 1 the value of the int turno and reset its value to 1 if it is increased over 4. I have put a call to repaint method at the end of PaintComponent as I had not before but still it doesn't work.

Comment: In the console, it does not write "Ejecutándose función de pintura de ficha" so I think the problem is that paintComponent is not being executed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RobertoGilLeón : Please, when you override the method of a Super Class inside the Base Class, do respect the `Principle of Encapsulation`, i.e. keep the Access Specifier same as much as possible. The `paintComponent(...)` method has `protected` access Specifier and not `public` :-) +1 though for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add repaint() to your Refrescar method:

```
public void refrescar() {

    jpanel.add(jlabel);
    jframe.add(jpanel);
    jframe.pack();
    jframe.repaint();
}
```

Comment: `ficha.repaint()` is actually the real thing :-)